# How do you replace a specific line of a file with python?

Tags: python, file

```
line_row = -1
file = open(file_path, 'r')
for number_of_lines in file:
    line_row = line_row + 1
    if '1234' in number_of_lines:
        lines = file.readlines()
        line = lines[line_row]
        print(lines)
        lines[line_row] = 'hello'
        file = open(file_path, "w")
        file.writelines(lines)
        file.close()
```

When I run this, it will delete everything that is before the nth line. I want it to replace only the nth line. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, using `enumerate`

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "some text" in line:
            lines[i] = "updated text"

with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think that the problem of my code is the part where I search for the line of the word ('1234'), not where i change the content of the line.